# NServiceBus batching a long running job

Tags: c#, .net, batch-processing, nservicebus, jobs

I'm working on a project that is using NSB, really like it but it's my first NSB solution so a bit of a noob. We have a job that needs to run every day that processes members - it is not expected to take long as the work is simple, but will potentially effect thousands of members, and in the future, perhaps tens or hundreds of thousands.

Having it all happen in a single handler in one go feels wrong, but having a handler discover affected members and then fire separate events for each one sounds a bit too much in the opposite direction. I can think of a few other methods of doing it, but was wondering if there is an idiomatic way of dealing with this in NSB?

Edit to clarify: I'm using `Schedule` to send a command at 3am, the handler for that will query the SQL db for a list of members who need to be processed. Processing will involve updating/inserting one or two rows per member. My question is around how to process that potentially larege list of members within NSB.

Edit part 2: the job now needs to run monthly, not daily.

Comment: Need a bit more detail please. What is the nature of the job which runs? Is it a SQL job? A Scheduled task? Some  cron-based backgrounder? Why would the handler be expected to "discover" which work it needs to do? Surely you should send the work needed to the handler.

Comment: It's a SQL job - needs to query the db to see what member's fit certain criteria, then update and insert a row or two for each member

Comment: @GoatInTheMachine see my answer. The great thing about using NBus is that if these transactions fail, they will be subject to retries just ensure your INSERTs are idempotent.

Comment: So the SQL job queries the db and creates the shortlist of members, or is this what the handler will do?>

Comment: Saga spins up > collates a list of records to process > sends message(s) > handlers then process these, one to perhaps update and the other to insert > after completing and zero records left to process defer a message for x number of days / weeks / months / years

Comment: @tomredfern sorry, used 'SQL job' confusingly...an NSB handler for a scheduled command will query db for shortlist of members, then...? Send a message per member? Process them all in one go? My question is how to deal with the processing in correct NSB style

Comment: @DrSchizo - *Saga spins up* - what starts the saga?

Comment: @GoatInTheMachine - is there a business requirement for all of the members need to be processed all at once in a batch once a month? Or would it be enough for each member to be processed at some point during the month?

Could you describe what happens during processing?

Comment: @pnschofield members in our system have collections of points that expire after an amount of time, with that time always being rounded up to the end of the month. Because each member's balance is materialised (this is not something we can change) we need a monthly job to update this balance, and also send out emails etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use a saga for this. Sagas should be lightweight and are designed for orchestration rather than performing work. They are started by messages rather than scheduled.

You can achieve your ends by using the built-in [scheduler](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/scheduling/). I've not used it, but it looks simple enough.

You could do something like:

1. configure a command message (eg StartJob) to be sent every day at 0300.
2. StartJob handler will then query the DB to get the work.

Then, depending on your requirements:

- If you need all the work done at once, create a single command with all the work in it, and send it to another endpoint for processing. If you use transactional MSMQ then this will succeed or fail as a unit.
- If you don't care if only some work succeeds then create a command per unit of work, and dispatch to an endpoint for processing. This has the benefit that you can scale out using the [distributor](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/msmq/distributor/) if you needed to.

> I'm working on a project that is using NSB...We have a job that needs
>   to run every day...

Although you can use NSB for this kind of work, it's not really something I would do. There are many other approaches you could use. A SQL job or cron job would be the obvious one (and a hell of a lot quicker to develop, more performant, and simpler).

Even though it does support such use cases, NServiceBus is not really designed for scheduled batch processing. I would seriously question whether you should even use NSB for this task.

Comment: Speaking to a few people who know NSB much better than me, it looks like you're correct that saga's aren't really appropriate. There is some tricky business logic and various other concerns (logging, auditing, correlation of stories of events and whatnot that are already 'solved') that mean I would rather do this in code than SQL however, so I will probably go with firing a command per member.

Comment: @GoatInTheMachine - I wish you luck! I have begun to view NSB as a kind of "every problem is a nail" tool, so I will always advocate for it being used for its original purpose, i.e., as a service bus.

Comment: I totally understand your point, and we have used Hangfire etc in the past for this sort of thing

Answer (score 1):

You mention a running process and that sounds like a job for a Saga (see https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas/). You can use saga data and persist checkpoints in different storage mediums (SQL, Mongo etc). But yes, having something long running then dispatch messages from the Saga to individual handlers is definitely something I would do also.

Something else to consider is message deferral (Timeout Managers). So for example, lets say you process x number of users but want to run this again. NServiceBus allows you to defer messages for a defined period and the message will sit in the queue waiting to be dispatched.

Anymore info just shout and I can update my answer.

Comment: What starts the saga? Also, best practise for saga's is that they are lightweight. Saga handlers should be concerned with sending/publishing only. All work should be done outside the saga.

Comment: Therefore, in my opinion, a saga is overkill for this use case.

Comment: Saga is perhaps overkill but is a little more flexible. I do agree with you that having a handler would be simpler but depends on whether you need to store state. Having a handler that orchestrates and sends messages to other handles is fine too. Saga guarantees one instance to be running, although you have this working on a single worker using Bus.SendLocal() as opposed to a distributed model.

Comment: Agree. Though I think NSB is overkill for this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

A **real** NSB solution would be to get rid of the "batch" job that processes all those records in one run and find out what action(s) would cause each of these records to need processing after all.

When such an action is performed you should publish an NSB event and refactor the batch job to a NSB handler that subscribes to these events so it can do the processing the moment the action is performed, running in parallel with the rest of your proces.

This way there would be no need anymore for a scheduled 'start' message at 3 am, because all the work would already have been done.

Comment: The task we're running is a time sensitive scheduled task - continuously materialising the work off the back of other events is not possible.

Comment: If the task is time sensitive you can still use the same mechanism, but instead of keeping the "batch" service running all day, you could start it at 3am using a scheduled task and let it stop itself when it's done.

Comment: The main difference between using this pattern and an old-style batch job is that the process doesn't need to execute some expensive query to determine the work to be done.  This is info is already available in the form of the accumulated events.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I might model this idiomatically with NServiceBus: there might be a saga called PointsExpirationPolicy, which would be initiated at the moment that any points are awarded to a user. The saga would store the user ID, and number of points awarded, and also calculate the date/time the points should expire. Then it would request a timeout callback message to be sent at the date/time these points should expire. When that callback arrives, the saga sends a command to expire that number of points from the user's account. This would also give you some flexibility around the logic of exactly when and how points expire, and would eliminate the whole batch process.